# Moving files with whitespaces and rename, if files already exist in the new folder

Tags: linux, bash, find, mv

I need to move files with names like `source (new file).c` to another directory and rename it if the file already exist there.

I tried a lot of things like

`for file in $(find ~/path/ -type f -name "*.c"); do`

or

`IFS=$'\0' for file in $(find ~/path/ -type f -name "*.c"); do`

**Update.1** For rename condition i try `if [ -f /this/is/the/path/${file} ]; then`
or `if [ -f "$file" ]; then`

or `if [ -f "$HOME/some/path/$file" ]; then`

i want user input like `read -p "some messege" msg` but I can't figure it out and the if statement don't work as well and i don't know why...

**fix it** When I run the script, I get errors for split names. Example:
`mv: cannot stat '(new': No such file or directory`

Can someone help me with this?

**Update.2** solution for find name with whitespaces: `find ... | while IFS= read -r name; do your command done`

**Update.3** solution for if condition how don't work: **check correct awnser**

My regrets

Comment: Would you be OK with the original file in the directory being renamed as opposed to the new file?

Comment: i want user input there, so the only problem is to get the full name of the file in the if condition  so i can modified then. Example: if file dont exist just mv, if file exist ask if you want to keep it (mv) or rename it, it work with all the other files but dont works with whitespaces. That's the case.

Comment: Copy/paste your code (including the #!/bin/bash (or other)) into https://shellcheck.net and fix any issues found there. 99% of the time, you need to use dbl-quotes on your variable names, i.e. `"$file"`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thanks a lot, i have some improvement but the problem continuous with the whitespaces.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to setup to test on this. But using parens in a filename could cause even more problems that using spaces. Learn from this problem and make your `.c` code follow the convention of using `_` chars instead of spaces, and no other non-alphnumberics! Good luck!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437673/move-files-containing-brackets-and-year-eg-1999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/path/to/the/source"      # original directory
dest="/path/to/the/dest"        # destination directory

find "$path" -type f -name "*.c" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d "" file; do
    f=${file##*/}       # extracts filename by removing everything before "/"
    if [[ -f $dest/$f ]]; then
                        # if the file already exists
        for ((;;)); do  # then enter a infinite loop until proper filename is given
            IFS= read -p "'$f' already exists. Input new name: " f2 < /dev/tty
            if [[ ! $f2 =~ [[:alnum:]_] ]]; then
                echo "'$f2' is not a valid filename."
            elif [[ ! -f $dest/$f2 ]]; then
                        # a proper filename is input
                break
            else        # the filename still exists
                f=$f2
            fi
        done
    fi
    mv -- "$file" "$dest/$f2"
done
```

- `find ... -print0` uses a null character as a filename delimiter
  to protect filenames which contain blank (whitespace, tab, newline ...)
  character.
- `read -d ""` corresponds to `-print0` and split the input on the null characters.
- `read < /dev/tty` avoids the conflict with the outermost pipeline
  fed by the `find` command.